# How To Use indentationLevel for differentiating Custom Cell at particular valueforKey"Level" in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i have made a demo which defines tableview in levels where section is only 1 but rows are defined according to levels. how can i set custom cell at cellforRowAtIndexPath level wise. 
This code works smooth when run without using CustomCell. but when i include customCell for particular level. THe Error like "[CustomCell txtAddress]not recognized as a selector" occurs. this only happens when i scroll the tableview.
In precise words the app crashes.

My Code is as follows:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad

{
[super viewDidLoad];
arraylist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
array5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
objects = @[@"Medical Services In Chicago",@"Medical Services On Campus"];
arrObjectValueChicago = @[@"Ronald McDonald® Children's Hospital of Loyola",@"Burn Centers",@"Gottlieb Hospitals"];
arrObjectValueCampus = @[@"Cardinal Bernardin Cancer Center1",@"Center for Heart & Vascular Medicine2"];
for (int i =0; i< [arrObjectValueCampus count]; i++) {
    dictListCampus1 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"level",[arrObjectValueCampus objectAtIndex:i],@"name", nil];
    [array5 addObject:dictListCampus1];
}
NSDictionary *dictListCampus = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Wellness Centers",@"name",@"1",@"level",array5,@"Objects",nil];
NSMutableArray *array6 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:dictListCampus, nil];
array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
for(int i = 0; i<[arrObjectValueChicago count];i++){
       dictList3 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"level",     [arrObjectValueChicago objectAtIndex:i],@"name", nil];
     [array3 addObject:dictList3];
}

        NSDictionary *dictList2 = [[NSDictionary    alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hospitals",@"name",@"1",@"level",array3,@"Objects",nil];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:dictList2, nil];
for (int i =0; i<[objects count]; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        dictionary =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[objects objectAtIndex:0],@"name",@"0",@"level",array2,@"Objects", nil];
        [array1 addObject:dictionary];
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        dictionary =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[objects objectAtIndex:1],@"name",@"0",@"level",array6,@"Objects", nil];
        [array1 addObject:dictionary];
    }


  }
        dictList = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:array1,@"Objects", nil];
        arrayOriginal = [dictList valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        [arraylist addObjectsFromArray:arrayOriginal];
  }





#pragma mark - TableView
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [arraylist count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       NSUInteger indentLevel = [[[arraylist    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"level"]intValue];

        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [CustomCell reuseIdentifier]];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = self.cells;
    self.cells = nil;
}
if (indentLevel == 0) {
    cell.lblHeader.text = [[arraylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.lblSubHeader.hidden = YES;
    cell.imgSubHeader.hidden = YES;
    cell.txtAddress.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnarrow.hidden= YES;
    cell.btnCall.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnCallNumber.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnHome.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnHomeAddress.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnUrl.hidden = YES;
    cell.imgline.hidden = YES;
    return cell;
}
else if (indentLevel == 1) {
    cell.lblSubHeader.text = [[arraylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.lblHeader.hidden = YES;
    cell.imgHeader.hidden = YES;
    cell.txtAddress.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnCall.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnCallNumber.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnHome.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnHomeAddress.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnUrl.hidden = YES;
    cell.imgline.hidden = YES;
    return cell;

}
else if (indentLevel == 2) {
    cell.txtAddress.text = [[arraylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.lblHeader.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnarrow.hidden= YES;
    cell.imgHeader.hidden = YES;
    cell.lblSubHeader.hidden = YES;
    cell.imgSubHeader.hidden = YES;
    return cell;

}
[cell setIndentationLevel:[[[arraylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"level"]intValue]] ;
return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tblist deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:  [CustomCell reuseIdentifier]];
   NSUInteger indentLevel = [[[arraylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"level"]intValue];

  if (indentLevel == 1) {

    [cell.btnarrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dwn1_arow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.imgSubHeader setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_active.png" ]];

}
   NSDictionary *d = [arraylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([d valueForKey:@"Objects"] ) {
    NSArray *ar = [d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
    BOOL isAlreadyInserted = NO;
    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
        NSInteger index=[arraylist indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
        if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
    }
    if(isAlreadyInserted) {
        [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
    } else {
        NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
        NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
            [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
            [arraylist insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
        }
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }

     }

 }
  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
            NSUInteger indentLevel = [[[arraylist  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"level"]intValue];

 if (indentLevel == 0) {

    return 40;
}
else if (indentLevel == 1)
{
    return 25;
}
else if (indentLevel == 2)
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomCell reuseIdentifier]];

    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11.5];
    CGSize myStringSize = [cell.txtAddress.text sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [cell.txtAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.txtAddress.frame.origin.x, cell.txtAddress.frame.origin.y, cell.txtAddress.frame.size.width, myStringSize.height)];

    if (myStringSize.height > 80) {
        myStringSize.height = 50;
        [cell.txtAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.txtAddress.frame.origin.x, cell.txtAddress.frame.origin.y, cell.txtAddress.frame.size.width, myStringSize.height)];
        cell.txtAddress.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.txtAddress.scrollEnabled = YES;
        myStringSize.height = 40;
    }
    //NSLog(@"String Size :: %f", myStringSize.height);
    return myStringSize.height+ 50;

}
else
    return 40;
  }
 #pragma mark - TableAnimation
-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar
{
     for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
    NSUInteger indexToRemove=[arraylist indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
    NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
    if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
        [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
    }

    if([arraylist indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
        [arraylist removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        [tblist deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                                [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: get the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335601/how-to-use-indentationlevel-for-differentiating-custom-cell-at-particular-valuef

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of txttext Outlet not set in your custom cell XIB. I can not see in your code if you have txttext outlet is present in your custom cell XIB. So please check your xib file by right clicking on file's owner and check if every outlet is referenced properly.

Comment: i saw the xib each and every tool is linked with their relative views.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use customCell then try,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forClass:(Class)class {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[class class] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(class)];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Add method in NSObject Category class,

```
+ (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)NibName {
    NSObject *cl = nil;
    if (NSClassFromString(NibName) != nil) {
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NibName owner:self options:nil];
        for (id cls in arr) {
            if([cls isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(NibName)])
            {
                cl = cls;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cl;
}
```

Call like

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self cellForIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath forClass:NSClassFromString(@"CustomCell")];
```

Comment: if i want to use multiple custom cell then the above code will work?

Comment: yes, you can use it to create multiple custom cel by reuse it

Comment: the method "loadNibNamed" which u have created where i have to call ? is it in TableViewCell Class or i have to make  NSObject class?

Comment: you need to make NSObject's category class

Comment: as i m new in iphone development can u help me out with a demo ?

Comment: create new file wizard will show you different template. Select Objective-c Category and give the category name like "Extends" or else and category on must be NSObject and copy that method and import it.That it.

Comment: where to use CellIdentifier method?

Comment: i mot getting how and where to use cellforIdentifier method. I used this in my viewcontroller class. i m getting error

Comment: in cellforrow data source method of table

Comment: u didnt understand what i m trying to say i meant to say How to use  the below method                                                    - (UITableViewCell *)cellForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forClass:(Class)class {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[class class] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(class)];
    }
    return cell;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom cell by this way:-

```
 NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

 TestCustomCell *cell = (TestCustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

This custom nib will be return.

And also check outlet are not properly configured. please set that.